# Añadir otra condición más

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

estoy haciendo la edición de un formulario, pero necesito hacer varias condiciones, por ejemplo; si el usuario no cargar foto se mantenga la misma y si el usuario no pone nada en el campo password se mantenga la misma que tenia, e hecho la parte de la foto pero no se como añadirle una condición más.

```
<?php
 include "../../conexion/conecta.php";

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];


 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
 strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
 {

//obtenemos el archivo a subir
$file = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
//comprobamos si existe un directorio para subir el archivo
//si no es así, lo creamos
if(!is_dir("../../images/usuarios/"))
    mkdir("../../images/usuarios/", 0777);


//comprobamos si el archivo ha subido
if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],"../../images/usuarios/".$file))
{
   sleep(3);//retrasamos la petición 3 segundos
   $usuario_cargo_foto = true;
}
}else{
    echo "Error Processing Request";
}

if($usuario_cargo_foto){
$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Usuarios Set nombre='$nombre', Password='$pass', foto='$file' where IdUsuario= $id ");
}
// Si el usuario no cargo foto, construyo la consula sql sin incluir la actualización de la foto, esto es para que se conserve la actual.
else{

$results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE Usuarios Set nombre='$nombre', Password='$pass' where IdUsuario= $id ");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías verificar si existe el `if (empty($_POST['pass'])) { $texto = null;
    }else{ $texto =  "Password='".$_POST['pass']."',"; }` con eso verificamos que si el pass vienen vacío no ponga nada, en otro caso se lo asignamos así a texto, para después poder hacer `$query = "UPDATE Usuarios Set nombre='$nombre', ".$texto." foto='$file' where IdUsuario= $id "` y despues quedaría así `$results = $mysqli->query($query);` , espero te sirva esta idea.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu ayuda @Tonatihu Fabian . Puedes modificar el código original? no se donde implantar eso gracias